# How can I execute a directive through a function and retrieve the style it creates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that randomly picks a color and assigns it to a new user as an avatar. The random-ness works and the directive works as I would expect it by adding `style="background-color: #RGBFunction"`. I need to extend this functionality a bit further but I can't seem to figure it out.

First, as you can see in the code the directive fires up as soon as the element passes through the DOM. But I would much rather the directive to fire up when the user starts typing a Name in the input field.

Second, once the `addNewContact()` function executes, the color is not being passed to the list of contacts. I would like to somehow absorb the  `style="background-color: #RGBFunction"` and pass it to the `color` field in my `contacts.json` Is that possible?

Here is the directive

```
 function randomBackgroundcolor() {
        return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        replace: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            //generate random color
            var color = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);

            //Add random background class to selected element
            element.css('background-color', color);
            //document.getElementById('newContact').style.backgroundColor = color;

        }
    };
 }
```

The HTML

```
    <md-dialog-content>
        <div class="md-dialog-content">
            <div class="mb-30 avatar-wrapper" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                <span class="md-fab md-initials md-large mb-15" random-backgroundcolor>
                    {{contact.name | shortName}}{{contact.lastName | shortName}}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
            <md-input-container class="md-icon-float" flex="100">
                <label>Name (required)</label>
                <input ng-model="contact.name" type="text" ng-required md-autofocus>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="md-icon-float" flex="100">
                <label>Last Name (required)</label>
                <input ng-model="contact.lastName" type="text" ng-required md-autofocus>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </md-dialog-content>
```

And the portion of the Controller that passes the new contact to the list. More can be seen by visiting the plunkr

```
function addNewContact()
{
        Contacts.unshift($scope.contact);
        closeDialog();
}
```

You can see the code in this [**PLUNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZG3YLDkC2ngSs7KmMYxi?p=preview)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link the scope with `replace: false`, The controller and directive are now using the same scope object, controller or directive will be in sync.
With scope accessible , add a `$watch` on the `contact.name` property.
When there is a change to the `name` update `contact.color`

```
function randomBackgroundcolor() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    replace: false,
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var color = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
      scope.$watch('contact.name', function(val) { 
        if (val !== '') { 
          scope.contact.color = color;
        }
      });
    }
  };
}
```

html : update the `span` element with ng-style to fetch the color from the object instead

```
<span class="md-fab md-initials md-large mb-15" ng-style='{"background-color":contact.color}' random-backgroundcolor>
```

let us know